# System Info shows Mint but Ubuntu 21.10 is installed -> can't upgrade to 22.04

Tags: upgrade, chromium, versions, 22.04

I have done a fresh install of 21.10 a while ago and today I wanted to upgrade to 22.04.

However, I have installed Chromium via the Mint repository since it's no longer in the Ubuntu repo.
After that my system info was telling me I was running Mint 20.3 which I'm not.

lsb_release -a says:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Linuxmint
Description:    Linux Mint 20.3
Release:    20.3
Codename:   una
```

The output from cat /etc/*-release is showing me:

```
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.3
DISTRIB_CODENAME=una
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 20.3 Una"
NAME="Linux Mint"
VERSION="20.3 (Una)"
ID=linuxmint
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint 20.3"
VERSION_ID="20.3"
HOME_URL="https://www.linuxmint.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.linuxmint.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://linuxmint-troubleshooting-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.linuxmint.com/"
VERSION_CODENAME=una
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

The output from apt-cache policy base-files is:

```
base-files:
  Installiert:           20.3.0
  Installationskandidat: 20.3.0
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 20.3.0 100
         -1 http://packages.linuxmint.com una/upstream amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     11.1ubuntu5 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 Packages
```

grep -Ev '(^#|^ *$|deb-src)' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* | nl is giving me:

```
1   /etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish main restricted
     2  /etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-updates main restricted
     3  /etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish universe
     4  /etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-updates universe
     5  /etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish multiverse
     6  /etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-updates multiverse
     7  /etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish-backports main restricted universe multiverse
     8  /etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security main restricted
     9  /etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security universe
    10  /etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security multiverse
    11  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gerardpuig-ubuntu-ppa-impish.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gerardpuig/ppa/ubuntu/ impish main
    12  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth-pro.list:deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main
    13  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/insync.list:deb http://apt.insync.io/ubuntu impish non-free contrib
    14  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mint-una.list:deb http://packages.linuxmint.com una upstream
    15  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list:deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal main
    16  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main
```

cat /var/log/installer/media-info is telling me:

```
Ubuntu 21.10 "Impish Indri" - Release amd64 (20211012)
```

Which is exactly what I have installed!
So I'm running 21.10 but the Chromium installation "hijacked" my system and is telling me that I have Mint 20.3

When I was trying

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

it did not succeed with:

"Neue Veröffentlichungen von Ubuntu werden gesucht
Aktualisierungen auf die Entwicklerversion sind nur
von der jüngsten unterstützten Version aus möglich."

(Sorry for german system, I hope it's understandable what it's telling me. Basically: won't let you update Mint to Ubuntu)

I already tried purging Chromium with no success.

So what can I do to upgrade my system to 22.04 without doing a fresh reinstall?
How can I "get rid" of the false system interpretation?

Comment: Take a look using `synaptic` - click Origin at the lower left. My bet is when you added that ppa, you pulled in so many packages that you turned your system into Mint.  To fix it, you can use `ppa-purge`.

Comment: Alright! Cheers!

So Synaptic is showing me that "only" the base-files are from "packages.linuxmint.com"
And it's in there twice. One says: "local/main (packages.linuxmint.com)" and another entry further down says: "una/main (packages.linuxmint.com)

All the other "origins" are either other PPAs or Ubuntu related.

Comment: `base-files` is the package that says what version your system is, so that is the one to replace.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help so far!
How do I reinstall the correct ones? Because "sudo apt install base-files" only tries to install Mint 20.3 again and says it's already current.
And do I need to get rid of the double entry at the end? The one that says "una/main"? Or will that be removed when I install the Ubuntu ones?

Comment: It's actually weird because I did the exact same Chromium install on my desktop, too, without having these "symptoms".

Comment: You can "pin" or "force" the version using Synaptic. I can't give details right now but googling should turn them up.

Comment: Found it. Doing it now. If I go quiet after that it could mean two things.
- I shot and killed my system :D
- I went to bed and to work tomorrow but will answer asap. Either way: thanks so much!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

That did it!
Forcing the "base-files" to use the impish repository as source did it and everything was back to normal.
The dual boot GRUB screen was still saying it's Mint but that went away with the system upgrade. Thanks!